# Unwanted Margin Between Element - Unable to Remove

Tags: html, css, margin

There is a large 'white-space' between my 'DIV: IMAGE' and 'DIV: SLIDER' that I cannot account for. I cannot see that I have coded a margin between the two elements and no matter what I seem to do to my stylesheet, I cannot remove it.
What part of the code is causing this? And what clean solutions are there? Many Thanks.

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 3em 0em;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}
.image {
  background-image: url("http://www.thestrandnyc.com/d/main/media/Destination/__thumbs_1200_700_crop/NY_City.jpg");
  background-size: 110% 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px 210px 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slider {
  padding: 2em 0em;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.slider p:first-child {
  color: #fff;
  background: #35AFBA;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 1.2em;
  position: absolute;
}
.slider p:nth-child(2) {
  color: #ff605f;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ff605f;
  background: rgba(230, 231, 231, 0.56);
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 0em 0em 0em 4.5em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="image">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="nav">

        <h1>Resume</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Skills</li>
          <li>Experience</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="me">
        <h2>Andrew Hardiman</h2>
        <p>Webdesigner & Developer</p>
        <p>Read More</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">

      <p>HTML</P>
      <p>css</P>
      <h3>I design and develop amazing websites that are sleek, easy-to-navigate and exiting to use.</h3>
      <p>Work with us to plan your digital marketing mix and achieve better results online.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I thought div#slider was inside div#image, but this turns out not to be the case. Debugging would be much easier if your indentation is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div.slider` is inside `div.wrap`, which has a `margin-top` and a `padding`. They cause the gap, and removing them will solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You `.wrap` element has `padding` of 3em and `margin-top` of 10px, try removing those 2 css rules and there should be no more white-space.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/haxj27mm/1/

```
.wrap {
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 80%;
   margin-top: 0px;
   padding: 0em 0em; 
   position: relative; 
   color: #FFF;
}
```